# Between operator in influxDB

Tags: time-series, influxdb

i want to select record **between** two date time string value in **influxdb**.  Example:
*select value from series where time between start_time and end_time*

I am querying like this. 
"select value from series time >= start_time and time <=end_time" 
Is this correct ??

Comment: i m selecting like this " select value from series time >= start_time and time <=end_time " is this correct.

Answer (score 3):

I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072637/how-to-get-the-sum-value-from-the-influx-using-a-time-range)

Let me know, if it solves your problem.

Comment: I am not looking for this, here you are using greater than and less than combined query, i want single between operator