# How to get the sum value from the Influx using a time range?

Tags: influxdb

I used Influx for recording some serial data, and show the reports of these data.

I have a requirement like this:

Get the total sum of the value in the time 07:00 AM to 09:00 AM from 2017-05-11 to 2017-05-17.

In mysql, this is very easy, since you can get this value using one query:

```
select sum(value) from series where time(time) >= '07:00:00' and time(time) < '09:00:00' and time > '2017-05-11' and time < '2017-05-19'
```

But in Influx(I'm using 1.0.2 now), I can't see any functions like this, did influx support the query like this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use this-

```
select sum(value) as summed_value from series where time> '2017-03-10 00:00:00' and time<'2017-05-10 00:00:00';
```

Also if you want to get data using hours also ,in such cases you can use

```
 select sum(value) as summed_value from series where time> now() - 2400h and time<now() - 1200h;
```

Let me know,if this solves your problem.

Comment: No, just like the example I listed, I want to get the sum across many days, not for only one day, say, I need the sum of the value at 7:00AM to 10:00AM from last Friday to today, so it will be 3 ranges not only one

Comment: there is no direct query for the same but you might achieve this by combining multiple queries and use group by in each of them .

Comment: this is not workable, do you mean I have to search for the sums everyday at the time, and sum them all together?